# PHP Library oci8.so without root rights

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

First off I am not sure if I am at the right place or better at serverfault.

I am working on a PHP project and need access to an Oracle 10g DB. The server I am using is provided and maintained from a 3rd party. Lets call them ABC. I have only a restricted user. So everytime I need something I have to ask them to install it. This worked fine until now.

The server is a RedHat server and ABC is only allowed to install software from the official repositories. We were able to install the Oracle Instant Client but did not find the PHP libraries within the repository.

Our second try was to find a rpm-package containing the OCI8 library which is compatible with the installed software. Unfortunatly we only found a version which needs a newer PHP version which, you guessed it, is not part of the official repository.

Okay, I checken php.net and they told me that I would be able to compile it myself as a shared library. Neat, that would be enough. The problem here is that i am not able to run the `phpize` command as locking failes (in terms of blocks) the process. The root-User from ABC would be able to do it, but they are not allowed to compile anything.

So here I am asking you guys if there is a way to download the files and use it as a shared library without installing, compiling or whetever. The server is a 64bit RedHat Enterprise 6:

```
Linux [SERVERNAME] 2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 15 10:48:38 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: This probably belongs on server fault, but I'm no expert.

Comment: Isn't it possible to connect to Oracle using PDO+Oracle Instant Client library files+ TNS config ?

Comment: I don't know. I am migrating an existing application. Or at least i a trying.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:
1. Set a proxy for pear:

```
pear config-set http_proxy http://[proxy]:[port]
```

2. Get sudo rights to use pecl
3. Install:

```
sudo pecl install oci8
```